# Two divs not floating correctly

Tags: html, css

Not sure what the problem is: http://watercookies.topfloorstudio.com/

If you scroll down to "Latest News", I'm trying to get the div with the class `.newscontentright` to be inline with the image on the left. I've wasted too much time trying to figure it out on my own. Any help?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to set the width of newscontentright

```
.newscontentright {
       width: 300px;
 }
```

And remove the following from between newscontentleft and newscontentright

```
 <div style="clear:both;"></div>
```

As a side note, learn to lay out pages without using clear. Use clear only when absolutely necessary, otherwise things get messy. 'Overflow: auto' is often a better solution.

In this particular case the clear is completely unnecessary so just remove it.

Comment: This worked and overflow: auto solved the issue I was using the clear for. Thanks so much.

Answer (score 0):

maybe try your clear before your first float?

```
<div style="clear:both;"></div>
<div class="newscontentleft">
<img class="imageshadow" width="178" height="122" alt="news1" src="images/news1.jpg">
</div>
<div class="newscontentright">   
<h3>Fall Blue Ridge Parkway “Bike for the French Broad”</h3>   
<p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Suspendisse vestibulum, turpis ut hendrerit porttitor, lectus ipsumegestas sapien, ac tristique metus quam id est. </p>
<a> href="#">Read the full article »</a>
</div>
```